# draw polyline between multiple markers using ngmap

Tags: ng-map

How to draw polyline between multiple markers using ngmap?

This is my ngmap code on dynamic marker using ng repeat

```
<div map-lazy-load="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" map-lazy-load-params="{{googleMapsUrl}}" class="fullmap">
<map center="{{mapCenter.lat}},{{mapCenter.lng}}" zoom="{{mapCenter.zoom}}" pan-control="true" scrollwheel="false" default-style="false"  >
    <custom-control id="searchCtrl" position="TOP_CENTER" index="1" on-click="doSearch()">
        <button>Search</button>
    </custom-control>
    <marker ng-repeat="pos in positions" position="{{pos.latitude}}, {{pos.longitude}}"
            title="({{pos.deviceTime| date:'medium'}}) GPS: {{pos.latitude}}/{{pos.longitude}}, Speed: {{pos.speed}}, Course: {{pos.course}}"
            id="pos{{pos.id}}"
            icon="{{'assets/green.png'}}"
            visible="true">
    </marker>
</map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505484/create-a-line-between-markers-using-ngmap)

So, i just need to create an array object of latitude and longitude for **path** in **shape** directive

HTML

```
<shape name="polyline" path="{{path}}" geodesic="true" stroke-color="#FF0000" stroke-opacity="1.0" stroke-weight="2"></shape>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.path = $scope.positions.map(function(position){
     return [position.latitude,position.longitude];
});
```